# Proper usage of the word Wifey

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, american-english, british-english

Could one use the word "wifey" instead of "wife"? I found many conflicting definitions online, Macmillan dictionary says it can be referred to as on'e wife in a humorous way or insulting way. Another meaning- It's referred to an old woman. I am not sure if the native US or UK speakers recognize this word and use it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a recognised word, but its use is either old fashioned, or humorous, or occasionally affectionate.

In normal, modern, usage, on most locations, no one would use the term as a common synonym for 'wife'.

There are some areas where it would be considered nothing more than an informal, affectionate, term for the speaker's wife.

Answer (score 1):

Although 'wifey' can be used affectionately, many people in English-speaking countries see the word as misogynist, sexist, and infantilising. There may be slight nuances of meaning, e.g. in American English, a single woman may be considered 'wifey' if she is stereotypically suitable marriage material for a sexist type of man, and in the UK, it may be a word used casually by husbands to refer to their wives.

Either way, it is **insulting**.

> ...why does this insult still hang around? And why does it infuriate
> so acutely?
>
> For me, it’s the reduction of my complex identity to a label that has
> the condescending, infantilizing singsong tenor with which you might
> speak to a child. Wifey. Baby. Honey. Sweetie.

[The term ‘wifey’ is sexist and infantilizing. (Washington Post)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/soloish/wp/2018/05/01/the-term-wifey-is-sexist-and-infantilizing-when-can-we-finally-get-rid-of-it/)

> wifey
>
> ​NOUN COUNTABLE ​BRITISH ​INFORMAL
>
> 1 an insulting or humorous word used for referring to someone’s wife
>
> 1a a woman, especially an old woman.
> This word is sometimes considered to be insulting.

[Wifey (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wifey)

Comment: I see I got one downvote, which I somehow expected. Perhaps some people think what I wrote was 'woke'? Still, I stand by it. Also one upvote. Thanks, whoever it was.

Comment: A single woman may be considered *wifey* in a dictionary of American English but in English speaking America a single woman is **never** considered *wifey*.  It exists only in the books.  *Wifely,* on the other had, is sometimes used to describe the traditional roles and expectations of housewives.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - 1. 'wifey a girl you care a lot about, she's more than just your girl.' Urban Dictionary (not a great source, but quite relevant for informal usages). 2.  a guide to 'Cyber speak' - 'What Does WIFEY Mean? WIFEY means "Girlfriend described as wife material."' - 3. I was sick and tired of hearing “wifey” or the phrase “wifey material.” Who said that because a woman cooks, has a degree, and a stable job she should be considered “suitable” for a serious partner and someone who doesn’t have all three isn’t? - MadameNoire

Comment: No disrespect to CyberSpeak, UrbanSlang, or MadameNoire, but I must disagree.   *Wifey* is not used that way and I do not accept those sources as authoritative.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - from time to time, authoritative sources lag behind current usage, especially casual forms. Are you saying it isn't insulting?

Comment: One must be careful about making blanket statements with respect to usage without considering location. In certain areas 'wifey' would be considered nothing more than an informal, affectionate, term for the speakers wife.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I do not know if it is insulting.  The last time I heard it used I think Fred Flintstone called his cartoon wife Wilma, *wifey*.  That was in a cartoon from the 1960's.  I've never heard it said since.  I think the modern AmE version of *wifey* is **the wife**.  Which I do consider offensive.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther  It is insulting in Britain, if you don't like sexist talk. It can be used to mean 'the little woman', or 'my insignificant little boring wife', 'my accessory woman', etc. It's the sort of thing that a certain kind of man says when he is with other men.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther - that's exactly my point. Fred Flintstone was a stereotypical traditional 1960s blue collar traditional husband in a 'prehistoric' setting.

Comment: Would you consider the term "hubby" to be equally sexist and insulting?

Comment: @WS2 - I might see it as accepting traditional sex-role stereotypes.

Comment: @WS2 - my partner and I see these words as, to put it succinctly, straight outta Stepford, if not Gilead.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey My wife doesn't much like them either, and neither are terms that we use - but I wouldn't describe either as "sexist" since the latter is a very subjective and contested word. But I will admit to having used *the wife* and *the missis* but always with KSPMI - defined by our children as a a "knowing sense of post-modernist irony". Anything is ok as long as you do it with KSPMI.

Comment: @WS2 - my kids roll their eyes when I try that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well mine are in their mid-forties! That may account for the difference!

Comment: @WS2 - my son is 43 and my daughter is 45.

Comment: I shake your hand - my son is 40, and daughters 45 and 46,