# Understanding the meaning in context of the word wifey

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I someone asks "How is your Wifey" what exactly does it mean? I checked the dictionary and found this definition of "wifey" - "a condescending way of referring to a person's wife." Does that mean if someone uses the word "Wifey", the person is saying it in a superior way, does that mean that the person is putting herself above someone's Wife? or is it just a casual way of referring to someone's wife and doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: The men might have different opinions, and circumstances alter cases, but I expect "wifey" would take a dim view of the diminutive. By the same token, ***girlie / sonny*** today are likely to be seen as insulting / disrespectful in many contexts (but ***lassie / laddie*** are more generally acceptable in Scotland). Bottom line though - as a non-native speaker you should avoid using any words like this unless you hear native speakers using such vocabulary *within the same group of people*. Otherwise you ***will*** be liable to cause offense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP doesn't seem to understand the implications of ***condescending*** in his cited definition

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why would that call for closing the question? I would think that would call for pointing out the presence of the word (in case he just skimmed over it) and explaining what it means (in case he doesn't know what it means).

Comment: @Jay: I think it would be off topic if OP had asked *What does "condescending" mean?*, and it's not obvious to me that the *actual*l question as asked is significantly different. But obviously the main problem here is it's basically a *How long is a piece of string?* question. Opinions and precise context vary wildly, just as lengths of randomly-selected pieces of string vary.

Comment: How is this question different from [your other question about "wifey"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326887/proper-usage-of-the-word-wifey) last week? What about those answers was unsatisfying? (others: feel free to CV with this; I don't want to use my CV hammer here)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, don't want to get into a long debate on this. If someone asked, "What does 'condescending' mean IN THIS CONTEXT?" I think that would be a legitimate question. RE "how long is a piece of string?" Hmm. If someone said, "I heard this is an offensive word. But how offensive is it?" that could be a fair question, especially coming from a non-native speaker. Like is it offensive on the level of "you're a mean person" or is it offensive on the level of the F-word or the N-word?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper usage of the word Wifey](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326887/proper-usage-of-the-word-wifey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Wifey" is an informal word for "wife". Depending on how it's used, it could be an insulting word, or it could be endearing.

If a man wrote a love letter to his wife and addressed it, "To my dear wifey", she'd probably be pleased. Even if she didn't like the word, she'd likely consider his intentions good.

Personally, if I heard someone refer to another man's wife as his "wifey", I'd consider it inappropriately personal. Like if someone else called your wife "my darling".

Frankly, I'd avoid using the word today. There was probably a time when it would have been appropriate, but in the 21st century people are much more sensitive about anything that could be considered demeaning or inappropriate.